# Call between two or more devices which are connected with WiFi - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

I don't know the that this question is easy or not, But I didn't found any thing related to this on the web.

Does anyone know the wifi library or other help having functionality of connecting two device with iOS and having functionality of creating call between these two connected device or we can create group and do the group call also?

Comment: have you check about voip?

Comment: In my case there is no server in between the devices...

Answer (score 0):

Setup you own WebRTC server and obtain absolute URL with its protocol. Make sure that has to be work within your network only. When your devices are in wifi / network. They can connect each other through absolute URL.

Refer - https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios/blob/master/README.md

Comment: there is no server in between the devices or internet connection so no WebRTC server in between devices also